# Is this normal? ReactJS and react-router-dom v6 - Accumulated styles

Tags: reactjs

so I'm building a website in ReactJS but I have a problem. I use the react-router-dom v6 library, but every element I add that has styles, they are accumulated in the head tag. Is this normal? I import the styles via import 'style.css'. I would appreciate your help, thanks.

[image: The accumulated styles]

[image: The routes code]